# Slow drain in upstairs jack/jill bathroom

Tags: drain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some causes/solutions for poor drainage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1100/what-are-some-causes-solutions-for-poor-drainage)

What is best way to repair slow draining water in bathtub?

Comment: See the following questions:
http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/what-could-cause-my-sink-to-drain-slowly
http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1100/what-are-some-causes-solutions-for-poor-drainage

Answer (score 0):

If this just started I would try Draino or Liquid Plumber, if that dosn't work you may need to clean the trap. Seems like I've seen ads for a plastic thing for pushing stuff out of drains or use a piece of wire or a large zip tie and work it into the drain pipe to break up the gunk then try the draino aggain.